# MySQL Joining two unrelated tables

Tags: php, mysql, json

On my website I have a form with a select field. On that field I give suggestions for the input with some ajax code. These suggestions are coming from a .json file I create dynamically on each key press.

So this JSON file is filled with a single list.

**JSON file:**

```
{
    "suggestions": [
        {
            "value": "Commandos: Behind Enemy Lines"
        },
        {
            "value": "Commandos 3: Destination Berlin"
        },
        {
            "value": "Commandos 2: Men of Courage"
        },
        {
            "value": "Commandos: Beyond the Call of Duty"
        }
    ]
}
```

However the list is made up from two tables. These tables share no relation to each other. Both table got a 'gamename' which is just a VARCHAR column and I want those two into one big list. What would be the best (most efficient) way to get a result from them in one list?

**Databases**

> Table 1 (giveaway)
>
> giveawayid | gamename
>
> -
>
> Table 2 (steam_app)
>
> appid | name | type

What I have working now is doing 2 separate lookups to MySQL and then place all results into one PHP array. I also do a array_search on each result to prevent duplicate entries.

```
<?php
// query - BQ Game List
$sql = "SELECT 
            gamename as value
        FROM giveaway
        WHERE gamename LIKE '$query%'
        GROUP BY gamename
        ORDER BY count(gamename) DESC
        LIMIT 50";
$result = mysqli_query($dbConnection, $sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $json['suggestions'][] = $row;
        // create one array with all results to make it easier to use array_search()
        $haystack[] = $row['value'];
    }
}

// query - Steam App List
$sql = "SELECT 
            name as value
        FROM steam_app
        WHERE name LIKE '$query%'
            AND (type = 'game'
                OR type = 'dlc')
        ORDER BY name
        LIMIT 50";
$result = mysqli_query($dbConnection, $sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        // Check if value isn't already in the array
        if (array_search($row['value'], $haystack) === false) {
            $json['suggestions'][] = $row;
            // create one array with all results to make it easier to use array_search()
            $haystack[] = $row['value'];
        }
    }
}

// No results
if (!isset($json)) {
    $json['suggestions'] = '';
}

// CLOSE CONNECTION
mysqli_close($dbConnection);

echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

Now I wonder how efficient this is. Since doing two seperate lookups and lots of array_searches sounds to me like 3 resource intensive actions. Since this query gets called upon on every key press in the form field. I wonder if a single MySQL query wouldn't be more efficient. For instance by using a UNION.

Any insight into this?

Comment: I'm afraid there are too many parameters to give you a concise answer. Telling mysql to get you the suggestions in a single query provides the possibility to optimize on the server. However, most approaches would involve changing your DB structure.

Comment: Why are there two different tables? You could copy all the info you want to search for into a new table. Will save you a lot of headaches in the long run, I think.

Comment: Because one is external data that from Steam that gets imported every day from a JSON. The other is local data.
Since I can not be sure the external data is always correct, I don't want to store them together.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT` will get the MySQL server to dedup the contents of each result set. That might help. Other than that, what you have is workable.

Comment: Use [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/union.html) to combine those two `SELECT` into one database call.